# Looping through enum with initializer gives unexpected result

Tags: c#, enums, literals

The enum I've created looks like this:

```
enum MonthOfTheYear : byte
{
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July = 0,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
}
```

As you can see, July has an initializer of 0.
This has some interesting (side) effects: there seems to be "pairing" of integer values. February ànd August now have values of 1, March ànd September have 2 etc.:

```
MonthOfTheYear theMonth = MonthOfTheYear.February;
Console.WriteLine(theMonth + " has integer value of " + (int)theMonth);
```

and

```
MonthOfTheYear theMonth = MonthOfTheYear.August;
Console.WriteLine(theMonth + " has integer value of " + (int)theMonth);
```

clearly show this. So far, weird as I find that, I'm willing to go along.
**EDIT:** I get that assigning July 0 makes the indices start over. I DON'T get why they can co-exist within the same enum.

BUT! IF I then loop through the enum and output all the underlying integer values, weirdness ensues.

```
MonthOfTheYear theMonth = MonthOfTheYear.January;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(theMonth + " has integer value of " + (int)theMonth++);
}
```

outputs

```
July has integer value of 0
February has integer value of 1
September has integer value of 2
April has integer value of 3
May has integer value of 4
June has integer value of 5
6 has integer value of 6
7 has integer value of 7
8 has integer value of 8
9 has integer value of 9
10 has integer value of 10
11 has integer value of 11
```

I was hoping someone could explain to me what's going on behind the scenes, because the integer values are successive, so I'm thinking this is outputting *as expected* but I'm not seeing it as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the
>   GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of one of those
>   enumeration members. However, it does not guarantee that it will
>   always return the name of the same enumeration member. As a result,
>   when multiple enumeration members have the same value, your
>   application code should never depend on the method returning a
>   particular member's name.

So, to sum it up, when you have multiple members with the same value, the name you get for a particular value is *any of the members with that value*.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Your program only stores the `byte` value of your enum. Everything else is deduced from the enum type, based on the `byte` value.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, when you specify a value in the definition of an enum, subsequent values number consecutively from there - and even if you specify `0` somewhere, the first value will start numbering from `0`. Thus your underlying `byte` values are:

```
enum MonthOfTheYear : byte
{
    January = 0, // not specified, so starts at 0
    February = 1,
    March = 2,
    April = 3,
    May = 4,
    June = 5,
    July = 0, // specified, so starts numbering from 0 again
    August = 1,
    September = 2,
    October = 3,
    November = 4,
    December = 5
}
```

When you increment an enum value with `++`, it just increments the underlying `byte` - it *doesn't* look at the definition of the `enum` and go to the element on the next line!

If this `byte` doesn't have a corresponding defined entry, that doesn't mean it's invalid at all - just that, when you convert the enum value to a string, you get the `byte` value as a string.

If the `byte` has *several* corresponding defined entries... Actually, I'm not sure exactly which entry converting it to a string will give you, but it's clearly not necessarily the first one.

Basically `MonthOfTheYear.February == MonthOfTheYear.August` so whether you're calling `ToString` on it or just looking at it in the debugger, there's no guarantee that one won't get switched for the other.

Comment: ok, thanks. That much seemed to be apparent. But how does that explain the jumping around the months...? And where did March go?

Comment: While everything is true, it doesn't explain why `((MonthOfTheYear)1).ToString()` returns `February` and `((MonthOfTheYear)2).ToString()` returns `September`

Comment: @Wim Good spot. It's picking September instead, since they both have the same value - I don't know the precise rules, but I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method

```
Enum.GetName
```

Here is an example:

```
using System;

public class GetNameTest {
    enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };
    enum Styles { Plaid, Striped, Tartan, Corduroy };

    public static void Main() {

        Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Colors Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), 3));
        Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Styles Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Styles), 3));
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       The 4th value of the Colors Enum is Yellow
//
```

You get an full explanation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.getname.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, the article seems to answer that. My apologies ;)

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly set july to be the first month in the enum. This messes things up. 
Try this:

```
enum MonthOfTheYear : byte {
        January,
        February,
        March,
        April,
        May,
        June,
        July,
        August,
        September,
        October,
        November,
        December
    }

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} has integer value of {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(MonthOfTheYear), i), i));
}
```

Because you set july to zero it resets the indexer from that point. If you want this strange order to be in place, consider rearranging the order in your enum.